# Check if file exists and display it - order of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Section on my website with a list of fixtures.
 When I click on one it loads the fixture information in a modal window - each club might have an image so I want to check if there is an image and if so display it otherwise display a generic image.
 Code is below:

```
$('#fixModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal

  var hclub = button.data('hclubid')


  imgpath = "/images/clubcrests/"
  homecrest = imgpath + hclub + '.jpg'
  gencrest = imgpath + 'generic.jpg'


$.get(homecrest)
    .done(function() { 
        homecrestsrc = "<img src='" + homecrest + "'>"

    }).fail(function() { 
       homecrestsrc = "<img src='" + gencrest + "'>"
    })

  var modal = $(this)


  modal.find('.fixmodhomec').html(homecrestsrc)


})
```

But first time I click on it I get the error:

> homecrestsrc is not defined

`$.get` seems to run after the `modal.find`.

If I click on it again it displays but always the image it should have from the previous time the button was clicked.
 How can I make sure the `$.get` bit runs first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is *asynchronous* - did you read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)? `modal.find` will have run long before the response from the [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) call has come back.

You need to move your logic inside the callbacks.

```js
$('#fixModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget),
      hclub = button.data('hclubid'),
      modal = $(this),
      imgpath = "/images/clubcrests/",
      homecrest = imgpath + hclub + '.jpg',
      gencrest = imgpath + 'generic.jpg',
      homecrestsrc;


  $.get(homecrest).done(function () { 
    homecrestsrc = "<img src='" + homecrest + "'>"
  }).fail(function () { 
    homecrestsrc = "<img src='" + gencrest + "'>"
  }).always(function () {
    modal.find('.fixmodhomec').html(homecrestsrc);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the confusing part of js/ajax. This code does not wait for an ajax reaponse, but instead jumps strait on to the next command. Meaning it will continue with your last 2 lines of code, and then the response will come thru, and then it will set homecrestsrc for the first time. Whatever you expect to be done AFTER you get a reaponse, you put in done and fail. So put your last or last 2 lines of code inside the done and fail functions.

Sry typing from phone so i cant explain too much, but hope you understand, it takes time to get it bcs this is not so obvious when you start

Comment: Cheers - move those scripts inside the done and fail and it is now working 100%

Answer (score 1):

The other answer kind of covered this... basically, if the code below the get request depends on that result, it needs to be inside the .done() block.

However, I'd also like to point out that having your image displaying depend on the whether a get request fails or not is bad practice. You should instead have your api route return true if that image exists or false if it doesn't. Then you can filter the correct picture in a .success() block.

.fail() should be reserved for debugging only.

Comment: I would agree with most of your post, but the last line is wildly incorrect. Failure events should be used when a promise / deferred truly  *fails* - this isn't exclusive to debugging. If you need some logic to occur when something doesn't go as planned, that's what `.fail` is for. Whether or not OP has written smart code is another matter entirely.